# Don't include tags in the title

Tags: javascript

I don’t understand the code ads to earn

I created a ads link but no income and not running Don't include tags in the title and the earning and cpm decreased Don't include tags in the title.Don't include tags in the title.

Comment: Did you include tags in the title?